# convert a given decimal number to binary and count the consecutive 1s and display it

Tags: python

Problem: convert a given decimal number to binary and count the consecutive 1s and display it

Sample Case 1: 
The binary representation of 5  is 101, so the maximum number of consecutive 1's is 1.

Sample Case 2: 
The binary representation of 13  is 1101 , so the maximum number of consecutive 1's is 2.

Solution:

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys


n = int(input().strip())
result = []
counter = 1
def get_binary(num):
    if num == 1:
        result.append(num)
        adj(result)
    else:
        result.append(num%2)
        get_binary(int(num/2))

def adj(arr):
    global counter
    for x in range(0,len(arr)-1):
        if arr[x] == 1 and (arr[x] == arr[x+1]):
            counter += 1
    print(counter)

get_binary(n)
```

It doesn't pass all the sample test cases. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try with 115. You'll get 5, you need 3. You're counting _all_ the arrays of 1, while you must retain the longest one.

Comment: What cases doesn't it pass?  What does it do in those cases?  Please show these, as required by the posting guidelines.

Comment: also this shouldn't matter with your test cases but your binary is backwards

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I get 4 with this code.

Comment: oh that's because the last 1s string is counted wrong. 4 indeed. Doubly wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

below is an simplified version that works

```
def func(num):
  return max(map(len, bin(num)[2:].split('0')))
```

- convert integer to binary representation `bin(num)`
- strips 0b from the binary representation `bin(num)[:2]`
- split the string on character 0 `bin(num)[2:].split('0')`
- find the string that has the maximum length and return the number

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I updated the answer with the explanation

Comment: I like that better. I'm out of upvotes right now (no kidding). Can you try changing the `lambda` with a simple `len` ? Will be even clearer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre done!! thanks for the idea..  :)

Comment: now your post is beginning to look like something good :) Those binary manipulation questions always end up by converting to a binary string and manipulate strings. This always frustrated me since I wanted to do everything with bit shifting...

Comment: BTW I couldn't resist editing your answer to add the `return` statement :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution using `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> def bn(i):
...     n = bin(i)[2:]
...     return n,max(len(j) for j in re.findall(r'1+', n))
...
>>>
>>> bn(13)
('1101', 2)
>>> bn(25)
('11001', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your counter logic is incorrect in a couple of respects, M. Fabre identified the main one.  The result is that you count the total quantity of follow-on 1s in all sequences combined, and add 1 from the initial value of counter.  rogue-one gave you a lovely Pythonic solution.  To repair this at *your* level of use, go into **adj** and fix ...

1. You don't use **counter** outside the function; keep it local.
2. Make a second variable that's the best string you've found so far.
3. Use **counter** for the current string; when you hit a 0, compare against the best so far, reset counter, and keep going.\

The central logic is something like ...

```
best = 0
counter = 0
for bit in arr:
    if bit == 1:
        counter += 1
    else:
        if counter > best:
            best = counter
        counter = 0

# After this loop, make one last check, in case you were on the longest
#   run of 1s when you hit the end of the bits.
# I'll leave that coding to you.
```

Answer (score 0):

Some clever answers in here, thought I'd add an alternative using a traditional efficient imperative approach.

This method first converts the number to a string binary representation. From there it updates a stack of longest values, and does a check to see if there is a longer value to be added. Thus you end up with a stack of values that are sorted by longest consecutive 1's. To choose the maximum, simply `pop()` from the stack.

```
def longest_consecutive_one(n):
    stack = [0]
    counter = 0
    binary_num = '{0:08b}'.format(n)
    length = len(binary_num) - 1
    for index, character in enumerate(binary_num):
        if character == "1":
            counter += 1
        if character == '0' or index == length:
            if stack[-1] < counter:
                stack.append(counter)
                counter = 0
    return stack.pop()
```

**Sample Output:**

```
>>> longest_consecutive_one(190)
5
>>> longest_consecutive_one(10)
1
>>> longest_consecutive_one(10240)
1
>>> longest_consecutive_one(210231)
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Output of below written code will give maximum number of consecutive one's in input decimal number.

```
    n = int(raw_input().strip())
    num = list((bin(n).split('b'))[1])
    num.insert(0,'0')
    num.append('0')
    count = 0
    store = 0
    for i in range(0,len(num)):
        if ((num[i]) == '1'):
            count+=1
        elif ('0' == (num[i])) and count !=0:
            if count >= store:
                store = count
            count = 0
    print store
```

Answer (score 0):

this one uses bit magic

```
def maxConsecutiveOnes(x): 

    # Initialize result 
    count = 0

    # Count the number of iterations to 
    # reach x = 0. 
    while (x!=0): 

        # This operation reduces length 
        # of every sequence of 1s by one. 
        x = (x & (x << 1)) 

        count=count+1

    return count 

# Driver code 
print(maxConsecutiveOnes(14)) 
print(maxConsecutiveOnes(222))
```

the output will be 3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    int count=0,min=0;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;n>0;i++)
    {
        if(n%2==1)
                {

                count++;
                  if(count>min)
                   {
                     min=count;

                   }
                }
            else
                {
                 count=0;
                 }
        n = n/2;

    }
       cout<<min<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The language wa python, not C++.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 1st answer is the best. I had done it in a similar manner and might be easier to understand.

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    bina=str(format(n,'b'))
    holder=bina.split('0')
    max_num = max(holder,key=len)
    print(len(max_num))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using **Loop** and **List**, as shown below:

```
def maxConsecutive(n):
  binary = format(n,'b')
  print(f"The Binary Represntation of the number {n} is = {binary}")
  length = len(binary)
  count =0 #Create a Counter Variable to Count the Number of 1's
  
  #Create a blank Array to store the values of number of Consecutive 1's:
  Store = [] 

  for i in range(length):
    #Check if the number is 1,if yes increase the value of counter variable
    if (binary[i]=='1'):
      count+=1

    #Check if the number is 0 or last digit of the binary number:
    #to store the value of counter in the list and set the counter variable to 0
    if (binary[i]=='0' or i == length-1):
      if (count!=0): #To not add count=0 in the List
        Store.append(count)
      count = 0

  print("The List of Number of Consecutive 1's is : ",Store)
  print("The Maximum Number of consecutive 1 is: ",max(Store))

#Driver Code:  
n = int(input("Enter the Number: "))
maxConsecutive(n)
```