# Code fails 4/9 cases while counting maximum consecutive 1s, how can I improve this?

Tags: python-3.x, binary, logic

Given a base-10 integer, convert it to binary (base-2). Then find and print the base-10 integer denoting the maximum number of consecutive 's in 's binary representation.

I cannot look at the test cases, this is a problem from Hacker Rank, so if anyone could help me understand what cases this fails, what is the problem in my logic and how to improve it.

The same question has been asked with the solution using map, but I have not learned that much so I have used only what I know
[convert a given decimal number to binary and count the consecutive 1s and display it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494491/convert-a-given-decimal-number-to-binary-and-count-the-consecutive-1s-and-displa)

Problem : 4/9 test cases failed

I also dont understand why this works in those 4 cases, since the counter(count) is not reset to 0, shouldn't the value keep on adding up ? If so when do i reset it to 0 ? Or what else could be done ?

Code:

```
n = int(input())

# Get remainder
def get_rem(n):
    rem = n%2
    return rem
# Get the next value
def get_val(n):
    val = int(n/2)
    return val

# Convert decimal to binary
inp = n
bina = []
while inp != 0:
    new_rem = get_rem(inp)
    bina.append(new_rem)
    inp = get_val(inp)

# The binary value
binv = bina[::-1]


# Find maximum consecutive 1's
longest = 0
count = 0
for i in binv:
    if i == 1:
        count += 1
    else:
        if count > longest:
            longest = count

print(longest)
```

Comment: Your conversion code fails at least for n=0. Your counting code counts all 1s, not just consecutive. You must reset the cont when you encounter a 0.

Comment: @DYZ I solved it by changing the else statement to check if input is 0 and reset the counter.
    elif i == 0:
        count = 0
And then set longest to count.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the last part to

```
longest = 0
count = 0
for i in binv:
    if i == 1:
        count += 1
    elif i == 0:
        count = 0
    
    if count > longest:
        longest = count
    
print(longest)
```

worked for me